# How to handle multiple requests in python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")

def get_data(url,subject,message_id):
        driver.get(str(url))
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Work Order Number']")))
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        data = driver.page_source
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        job_url = driver.current_url
        print("Your job_url: " + str(job_url))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        work_order_number_data = soup.find(text="Work Order Number")
        print(work_order_number_data)

def get_prtfolio_datas():
    email_content = ""
    message_id = ""
    from_email_address = ""
    email_html_content = ""
    subject = ""
    to_address = ""
    try:
        arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
        for key in arguments.keys():

            if key == "body-html":
                email_html_content = arguments[key].value
            else:
                logging.info("Data: key: " + str(key) + "value: " + str(arguments[key].value))
                data = "%s=>%s" % (key, arguments[key].value)
                print(data)
                return "No data"
        process_status = get_data(email_html_content)
        print(process_status)
get_prtfolio_datas()
```

Is there any solution to handle multiple requests using python selenium? When I post data from Postman simultaneously it stuck.email_html_content is the data that I am posting from postman. But I post multiple requests. This is a sample code. Is there any method whether like multithreading or multiprocessing to handle this issue? 3 requests at the same time but 1 request gets broken down.